# Restoring navigationItem.title after removing navigationItem.titleView

Tags: ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

My App has 2 tabs (***tabA*** and ***tabB***), based on location the I set the `navigationItem.titleView` of ***tabB*** to a `UIImageView` when `- viewWillAppear:` is called.

The default behaviour of ***tabB*** is to simply display a title, e.g:

[image: Default Title]

The issue is when the location changes and I remove the  `UIImageView` `navigationItem.titleView` (using `- removeFromSuperview`), the default title has also disappeared and trying to set it with:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"TITLE";
```

Does not work. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply setting:

```
navigationItem.titleView = nil;
```

Will restore the text title.